# oracle regex_replace

Tags: regex, oracle, replace

we need to find and replace string in oracle using regex_replace

i have shared link for regex details https://regexr.com/3qvaq

we have to find specific string in the text i.e given below

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="129b943d-6508-45f4-bf3a-1cca8a44a16d" ac:name="expand" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="title">Table of Contents</ac:parameter><ac:rich-text-body>
<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="702e9620-1fd3-4941-be04-bd6d00a8dfe4" ac:name="toc" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="maxLevel">3</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="outline">true</ac:parameter>
<ac:parameter ac:name="style">none</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="printable">false</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></ac:rich-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

Comment: You haven't said which bit you want to replace, or what you want to replace it with. Have you looked at manipulating it as XML rather than as a plain string?

Comment: Can you define the properties of the specific string you've to find? If you don't, I doubt you or anyone else here can help you find it :)

Comment: @Alex Poole Replace part is easy if i could find the string in the complete text which i have saved in the regex link.The complete string is not in xml representable format.

Comment: @Jorge.V The string has two elements ac:name="expand" and ac:name="toc".These elements have a start and end tag of ac:structured-macro.There could be others parameter as part of these elements.Also note "toc" element is a child of "expand" element.